# Update a column in the same query as it is to be made in?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

In SQL Server, I am trying to create a temp table then join based on the unique index key criteria set forth, organizing them based on their system numbers, it looks a little something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[SysNr] AS [oldSysNr], t1.[SysNr] AS [newSysNr], 
    t1.[Year], t1.[WorkTm], t1.[AMSTC], 
    t1.[AJCC], t1.[ShifNum], t1.[FMN]
INTO
    #TEMPTABLE
FROM 
    AppData.SCHED AS t1
JOIN
    AppData.SCHED AS tS ON t1.ShifNum = tS.ShifNum
                        AND t1.WorkTM = tS.WorkTM
                        AND t1.FMN = tS.FMN
WHERE
    t1.Year = 2019;
```

This will essentially give me the old records needed by the oldSysNr column as the year is the param I am looking at. However, I need to update the newSysNr column in the same query, no separate query to update. Is there any way that this can be achieved? I only know of doing update as a separate query.

Here is the data that is produced from the query:

```
oldSysNr NewSysNr  Year  WorkTm  AMSTC  AJJC  SHIFNUM  FMN  
-----------------------------------------------------------
24        24       2019     3    WVB    GH      9     YUBMS
25        25       2019     3    BMS    MJ      8     YUBMS
26        26       2019     3    BMS    PP      8     MJUNL 
27        27       2019     4    ZMG    MJ      5     MJUNL
28        28       2019     5    BR     OP      3     COLHP
```

Here are the results that are desired:

```
oldSysNr NewSysNr  Year  WorkTm  AMSTC  AJJC  SHIFNUM  FMN  
-----------------------------------------------------------

 24        57        2019     3    WVB    GH      9     YUBMS
 25        58        2019     3    BMS    MJ      8     YUBMS
 26        59        2019     3    BMS    PP      8     MJUNL 
 27        60        2019     4    ZMG    MJ      5     MJUNL
 28        61        2019     5    BR     OP      3     COLHP
```

As mentioned, the param it is looking at is the year, and given that, the entire idea is that it would update NewSysNr provided that it was given the same join statement but it would be another year like 2020. Help in any given way on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: And have a look at your query. As written, that's not valid SQL. What's `t1`? Is that a self-join? Have a look at [this post](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: @EricBrandt I don't see anything wrong with the query.

Comment: @Eric he probably meant t2 since there there isn't a `.` to make that table fully qualified like it is above. However, those results wouldn't be returned from the query since they are selecting `INTO #TEMPTABLE`. OP really needs to provide sample data and expected results as Gordon requested.

Comment: @Eric, the latest edit fixed most of the issues. There were invalid aliases; probably a copy/paste/anonymize issue, but I wondered if a join was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to nest a subquery in the `FROM` clause. In other words, instead of selecting columns `x,y,z` from the table itself, you can replace the table name with a query which uses an updated `WHERE` clause.

So in this case it would look something like this: (Note: you may need to adjust the aliasing in the subquery...I'm just lazy. Also, you don't need to select all the columns in the subquery. The query in parenthesis is the subquery)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        tS.[SysNr] AS [newSysNr], t1.[oldSysNr]
        t1.[Year], t1.[WorkTm], t1.[AMSTC], 
        t1.[AJCC], t1.[ShifNum], t1.[FMN]
    INTO
        #TEMPTABLE
    FROM 

(SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.[SysNr] AS [oldSysNr]
    t1.[Year], t1.[WorkTm], t1.[AMSTC], 
    t1.[AJCC], t1.[ShifNum], t1.[FMN]

FROM 
    AppData.SCHED AS t1
JOIN
    AppData.SCHED AS tS ON t1.ShifNum = tS.ShifNum
                        AND t1.WorkTM = tS.WorkTM
                        AND t1.FMN = tS.FMN
WHERE
    t1.Year = 2018)

AS t1
    JOIN
        AppData.SCHED AS tS ON t1.ShifNum = tS.ShifNum
                            AND t1.WorkTM = tS.WorkTM
                            AND t1.FMN = tS.FMN
    WHERE
        t1.Year = 2019;
```

Comment: will this update the NewSysNr column to properly reflect the desired changes?

Comment: Upon modifying the query, the query in itself works fine, but the problem still remains that I can't update just one of the two columns new or oldSysNr. It still changes both, when I need one of them to change.

Comment: Did you remove the new or oldSysNr from the select statement in the subquery? I'll go ahead and do it in my answer...